# Set variable in Thymeleaf dialect

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I am creating own MarkupSubstitutionElementProcessor:

```
public class PaginationElementProcessor extends AbstractMarkupSubstitutionElementProcessor {

    ...

    @Override
    protected List<Node> getMarkupSubstitutes(Arguments arguments, Element element) {
        FragmentAndTarget fragmentAndTarget = new FragmentAndTarget("pagination", WholeFragmentSpec.INSTANCE);
        List<Node> nodes = fragmentAndTarget.extractFragment(arguments.getConfiguration(), arguments, arguments.getTemplateRepository());
        return nodes;
    }

}
```

And my pagination.html looks like this:

```
<p th:text="${page}">1</p>
```

How do I set a new variable in my ElementProcessor so that it can be used in my template?

Answer (score 0):

When defining a new processor that will extend your AbstractMarkupSubstitutionElementProcessor, override the processElement method :

```
@Override protected ProcessorResult processElement(Arguments arguments, Element element) {
    final Map<String,Object> localVariables = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    ...
    return ProcessorResult.setLocalVariablesAndProcessTextNodes(localVariables, true);
}
```

I am not sure that the processElement will be called in your case but if it is, that should give you access to the hashmap strings in the template.